# I'm trying to add customer segments to a Shopify discount app that I'm building, however I'm stuck

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

So this is the first-ever app that I'm building for Shopify, I usually work with WordPress so I'm so very far out of my comfort zone. I'm building a discount app using Shopify's own tutorial https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/selling-strategies/discounts/experience.

I've got all this up and running, however, I'd like to add a customer segment picker so the discount only works with specific customer segments, this way I can add automatic discounts based on customer segments.

I've tried integrating the customer eligibility card through the discount-app component. https://shopify.dev/docs/api/discounts/components/customer-eligibility-card

I'm just stuck as it uses a file import { fetchGraphQL } from "./authenticatedGraphQL"; // A request to proxy the GraphQL request. I have no idea what this does and how to replicate it to get this function working, any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement it yourself. I suggest using the `useAuthenticatedFetch` hook that is created automatically under `web/frontend/components` when you generate a new app using Shopify CLI.